# Unpack jar contents after creating it in maven

Tags: maven

I have this plugin in my pom.xml that creates a jar file and place it somewhere :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../../web/src/main/docroot/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I want to extract this jar into some directory after creating it. How can I do that ?

Comment: This looks like a web project but based on a correct configuration and folder layout that shouldn't be necessary. Can you show your full pom file and the structure of your project and what you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution and it works for me:   :)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra</groupId>
                        <artifactId>Shapeloader</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <excludes>META-INF/**</excludes>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../../../web/src/main/docroot/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```